# How to send a file from server to android phone

Tags: php, android, file, webserver

How to send or download a file from a local web server to android phone ? I am able to upload a file to server. In my problem, after the file has been uploaded to server, Server will process the file and creates an output file which needs to be given back to Android phone. For uploading I used php. File can be of image or text type.

Comment: How is this implemented on Android? Are you uploading to the server through an Android app? If so, what does the server return?

Comment: And what speaks against implementing the download also in php?

Comment: @JoelAuterson : Yes.. I am uploading to server through an Android app...When the user selects file to upload, php script on server is called to save the file..HTTP Url connection is used to connect to server. Server returns response code of upload status whether it was successful or not..

Comment: @arkascha: I'd avoid using PHP on Android unless it's totally, utterly necessary.

user2548073: There are several ways to go about this - I'd have the Android device start listening on a port, then the server can send when the processed file is ready. It could also long-poll, then return to the device a URL to the processed file.

Comment: @arkascha : Yeah.. but I am new to php..I need to view through implementation of download in php.. But is it possible to send a file directly to android from a web server either through php or servlets.

Comment: @JoelAuterson Obviously I was referring to using php on the _server side_! I assume that for the OP as well. What would you need that for on the client side?

Comment: No, you cannot send a file from a webserver to a smartphone in an active manner (read: direct push), since you cannot contact the smartphone (because of the network topology). You either send it as reply to the upload initiated by the smartphone (if processing is fast enough). Or you have to either poll the server for the result on a regular base or use a long call approach or similar.

Comment: @arkascha: Apologies - I think it's obvious that PHP will be used server-side, though. Nothing speaks against that.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your comments. I will try polling or reply after upload.